# No one knows why we are exactly using wsdl for server to respone

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl

Please some one explain why we use wsdl instead of soap request from server side to client side and why we are using soap request/response from client side to server side please someone explain me with example are suggest me with good links with some real time example

And also use of skeleton and stubs.

Then important thing why we are moving to spring mvc to web Service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic difference between SOAP and REST is SOAP only supports XML data where as REST supports XML, JSON, TEXT, etc..

There are two part in every webservice one is "consumer" and another is "producer",. When a producer produce a resource after that he has to publish that resource for which a consumer can access that resource. For this WSDL is used. WSDL is nothing but web service description language, it describes the resource (interface/implementation class).By using the WSDL endpoint a consumer will access the resource provided by provider.

We are not moving from Spring MVC to Web Service. Both are different things.

Example : 
through IRCTC site we are booking a railway ticket right. And again we can book the ticket using goibibo site also. but the parent is always IRCTC. So how goibibo sends the data of the customer to irctc to book a ticket. this is done with the help of web service.

Comment: rest only supports http protocol but soap supports almost all the protocol.

Comment: bro from server it send wsdl xml y it be like that can we use soap to send response

Comment: SOAP is nothing but a wrapper to a xml. There will some messaging format used for passing data between consumer and provider and xml,json are among them.